# Why does `getfacl` output for basic permissions differ from `ls -al`?

Tags: permissions, access-control-list

I have a directory that shows `r-x` group permissions in `ls -al` output:

```
mburr@burrvm-mint20:~$ ls -ald /media/mburr
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 17:11 /media/mburr
```

The `ls -al` output also shows that the directory has an ACL applied to it (the "+" at the end of the permsissions set) , so I looked at that with `getfacl`:

```
mburr@burrvm-mint20:~$ getfacl /media/mburr
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/mburr
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mburr:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

That output shows the ACL entry that allows my user to read and traverse the directory (`user:mburr:r-x`), but what got my curiosity is that `getfacl` says that the base group permission is `group::---` which is different than what `ls -al` showed (`r-x`).

I'd like to understand why and hope someone can explain.

Answer (score 2):

When an ACL has a `mask` entry, *that* `mask` entry is what shows up in the "classic" group permissions displayed by `ls -l`.

If a `mask` is not explicitly given when an ACL is created, the default value is the union of:

- ACL_USER (rights granted to a named user - `user:mburr:r-x` here)
- ACL_GROUP_OBJ (rights granted to the `group` entry - `group::---` here)
- ACL_GROUP (rights granted to named groups - not used in the example)

In this case, the union of `user:mburr:r-x` and `group::---` is `r-x` so that is what the `mask` was set to and that is what the "classic" group permission bits display.

This is documented in the [acl(5) manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html#CORRESPONDENCE_BETWEEN_ACL_ENTRIES_AND_FILE_PERMISSION_BITS):

> CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND FILE PERMISSION BITS
>
> ...
>
> If the ACL has an ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_MASK entry.  Otherwise, if the ACL has no ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_GROUP_OBJ entry.

Note: I found SUSE's documentation for [Access Control Lists in Linux](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP5/html/SLES-all/cha-security-acls.html) very helpful.